# Can't access atribute of a class

Tags: asp.net, class, attributes

I wrote a code to get the user attributes that match HttpContext, but when I'm trying to access the User attribute isn't visible from an external class. Example this is my Auth Class and the User attr.

```
 public class Auth
{

    IBaseRepository<User> _users;

    public Auth(IBaseRepository<User> user)
    {
        this._users = user;
    }

    private const string UserKey = "simpleBlog.Atuh.UserKey";
    public virtual User User
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;

            var user = HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] as User;

            if (user == null)
            {

                user = _users.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user == null)
                    return null;

                HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] = user;

            }

            return user;
        }
    }

}
```

And to get the user from an external class the showed option are "Equals", "ReferenceEquals".

**have to mention i'm using dependency injection**

Comment: a solution is to make User static, but I cant because injecting dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to instanciate the class using new keyword. If you don't instanciate the class then you are only offered class methods that are marked with static keyword.

```
var baseRepository = new BaseRepository<user>();
var auth = new Auth(baseRepository);

// Now you can access auth.User
console.log(auth.User.Name);
```